# Problem in integrating spring boot application with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I want to integrate Keycloak with spring boot application. The problem is that at the end, I got 403 forbidden error when calling the protected endpoints.

Following is my decoded JWT token, which is issued by Keycloak. I have a client, which is named clientApp1, and a realm role, which is named clientApp1User and mapped to the created user. Following is my decoded JWT token:

```
{
 alg: "RS256",
 typ: "JWT",
 kid: "ZWDbgcSI8nD2Yq4LA6hxYcsTbnf6y6Zj8PKyUobE_qE"
}.
{
 exp: 1666444432,
 iat: 1666444132,
 jti: "e6883855-ef20-4fac-95dd-8f13bd0ae552",
 iss: "http://localhost:12500/auth/realms/sampleRealm",
 aud: "account",
 sub: "80e1e45f-49fb-4a5a-9a60-b0057d291c53",
 typ: "Bearer",
 azp: "clientApp1",
 session_state: "c22af762-7be9-4150-94d5-8bd35065ac57",
 acr: "1",
 allowed-origins: [
  "http://localhost:11501"
 ],
 realm_access: {
  roles: [
   "clientApp1User",
   "offline_access",
   "uma_authorization",
   "default-roles-samplerealm"
  ]
 },
 resource_access: {
  account: {
   roles: [
    "manage-account",
    "manage-account-links",
    "view-profile"
   ]
  }
 },
 scope: "email profile",
 sid: "c22af762-7be9-4150-94d5-8bd35065ac57",
 email_verified: false,
 name: "user1FirstName User1LastName",
 preferred_username: "user1",
 given_name: "user1FirstName",
 family_name: "User1LastName"
}.
[signature]
```

Moreover, here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ResourceServerSample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ResourceServerSample</name>
    <description>ResourceServerSample</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Since, I want to use Security annotations to secure my end points I have set the security configuration as following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
```

Finally, in order to protect my endpoints I have used annotations like following:

```
@RestController
public class TestControllers {

    // Public endpoint
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public ResponseEntity<String> welcome() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Welcome to the unprotected endpoint");
    }

//    @RolesAllowed("clientApp1User")
//    @Secured("clientApp1User")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('clientApp1User')")
    @GetMapping("/clientApp1User")
    public ResponseEntity<String> clientApp1User() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("clientApp1User protected endpoint sends its regards");
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_email')")
    @GetMapping("/testScope")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testScope() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("testScope protected endpoint sends its regards");
    }
}
```

The problem that I face is that the endpoint, which is protected with @RolesAllowed("clientApp1User") or @Secured("clientApp1User") or @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('clientApp1User')") returns 403 forbidden, when it's called with a valid access token.

On the other hand endpoints with annotations like @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_email')") or @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_profile')") return 200 Ok.

I believe spring boot can not accurately parse the JWT token and only excepts values in scope claim with the prefix <SCOPE_> and as an authority.

Can any one help me to fix the problem and use the **RolesAllowed/Secured/PreAuthorize** annotations to secure the endpoint with **declared roles in realm_access and resource_access claims**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles are private claims: it is neither in OAuth2 nor OpenID specs and each authorization-server provider uses its own.

You have to provide your own `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticatonToken>` @Bean to map authorities from `realm_access.roles` (and maybe `resource_access.clientApp1.roles` if you enable client level roles in Keycloak) to everride Spring-boot default which turns `Jwt` into `JwtAuthenticationToken` (which can be fine) with authorities mapped from `scope` claim, adding `SCOPE_` prefix (which is not what you want).

Complete samples here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials which cover various servlets scenarios with @controller tests.

For reactive apps or secured @Service & @Repository tests, see in https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples (but it contain less explanations than tutorials, so start with tutorials and move up to samples for your exact use-case)

#### Sample

With the help of spring-boot 3 starters from the repo linked above, configuration for Keycloak can be as simple as (just adapt properties for any other OIDC provider):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <!-- depending on your use-case, you might replace !-->
    <!-- "webmvc" with "webflux" (for reactive apps) and !-->
    <!-- "jwt" with "introspecting" (for access-token introsepection instead of JWT decoding) -->
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity()
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```
#This illustrates configuration for accepting identities from both
# a Keycloak instance with authorities mapped from realm_access.roles and resource_access.account.roles
# an Auth0 domain with authorities mapped from roles and permissions
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.account.roles
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].location=https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].authorities.claims=roles,permissions

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowed-origins=https://localhost,https://localhost:8100,https://localhost:4200

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/actuator/health/readiness,/actuator/health/liveness,/welcome
```

#### Bonus

As already spoiled, in tutorials and samples, you'll see how to mock OAuth2 identities (with authorities) during unit and integration tests.

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SampleController.class)
@AutoConfigureAddonsWebSecurity // this is required only if you use one of the starters above
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
class SampleControllerTest {
    @Test
    void whenAnonymousThenGetWelcomeIsOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/sample")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void whenAnonymousThenGetClientApp1UserUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/clientApp1User")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth("clientApp1User")
    void whenClientApp1UserThenGetClientApp1UserOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/clientApp1User")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this example on github.
The problem right now is that you need to add your roles to the Security Context of Spring Boot.

```
    public static class CustomJwtConfigure implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {

@Override
public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
    var tokenAttributes = jwt.getClaims();
    var jsonObject = (JSONObject) tokenAttributes.get(REALM);
    var roles = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(ROLES);
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.forEach(role -> grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role)));
    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
}
```

}

[Link to github account](https://github.com/kesaven8/resourceServer-spring-boot)

Comment: You are mapping authorities from a single claim (not realm and resource_access as asked). Last, you should have a look at the tutorials I linked in my answer for a solution to configure role claims from properties.

Comment: The @Secured however will still not work as it requires to start with the Prefix ROLE_

Comment: `realm_access.roles` is one claim (with string list value). `resource_access.account.roles`  is an other claim with roles. And there can be as many `resource_access.{client-ID}.roles` claims as there are client roles mapper enabled in Keycloak. Again, refer to the tutorials linked in my answer to see how to do that (and add whatever prefix you need) .